# Xubuntu on HP Mini 1000 - how to install WLAN drivers?

Tags: wireless-networking, xubuntu, hp-mini

I've added Xubuntu to my Windows XP HP Mini using Wubi. It boots fine into Linux, but doesn't have the Wifi drivers installed. How can I get them installed? I don't have a USB-ethernet adapter.

Answer (score 1):

The HP Mini 1000 has a very well hidden ethernet port on the left side under a rubber port cap. If you have wired Internet access, just connect an Ethernet cable and you can download the drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Download them to another machine, transfer them to a USB stick, attach USB stick to HPMini, read drivers from USB stick.

Don't have another machine available? Boot HPMini into WinXP, download drivers, transfer them to a USB stick, leave USB stick attached to HPMini, read drivers from USB stick.

Comment: I think I found the drivers, but they are in source form.  That'd mean I'd then have to install GCC etc., but with no network connection I'd have to download all the packages and dependancies to a flash drive then install all that.  Surely there's an easier way?